# Connect C++ code With A Car game

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, image-processing, opencv, c++11

I am doing a project in opencv. I want to control the car through hand gestures. Now can anyone please help me regarding how to connect my program with the game. what steps should I follow. So i can send the signals to car game.

Comment: Well I have aleady recognized all the gestures needed to control the car. I just want to send the signal to the game. but i dont know how to do it

Comment: "how to connect my program with the game": What is "the game"? In general, games are programmed to respond to actual controllers: keyboards, mice, USB devices, etc. They usually aren't intended to take input from arbitrary programs.

Comment: the game is need for speed. and i want to control it through hand gestures. And video is taken from Microsoft Kinect. And i am using Opencv for image processing

Comment: Please close this question, it's overly broad. @user1429181 Investigate the Windows' API: `SendMessage()` and `PostMessage()` to [send keys to another window](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10011814/176769).

Answer (score 3):

You gestures should be numbers. Each gesture is represented by a number.

You send those numbers as an output of your program. Your game uses numbers as input, and each number determines an action.

With your current description of the problem I cannot be more specific.